# lua debug.traceback

Tags: debugging, lua, backtrace

I want to call the lua function `debug.traceback()` in c++ to get the trackback information in c++, so I added the function in c++ like  this:

```
int luaErrorHandler(lua_State *m_state) {
    if (!lua_isstring(m_state, 1))
        return 1;
    lua_getfield(m_state, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX, "debug");
    if (!lua_istable(m_state, -1)) {
        lua_pop(m_state, 1);
        return 1;
    }
    lua_getfield(m_state, -1, "traceback");
    if (!lua_isfunction(m_state, -1)) {
        lua_pop(m_state, 2);
        return 1;
    }   
    lua_pushvalue(m_state, 1);  /* pass error message */
    lua_pushinteger(m_state, 2);
        lua_call(m_state, 2, 1);  /* call debug.traceback */

    return 1;
}
```

and then I use `lua_pushcfunction(L, luaErrorHandler)` to push it into the stack , and use `lua_insert()` to move the function to the bottom, then `lua_pcall(L, nArgs, 1, errIndex)` to call the lua function. The stack should be like this at this time: ..luaErrorHandler , func, arg1 , arg2....

The problem is when I called the function, somehow the function changed the stack inside itself( I think..) , so I get the error "attempt to call a number value", and it goes correctly when I was not using the error handler function.
Is there any advise on how to use `debug.traceback()` correctly? Or how can I debug this problem cause I totally have no idea how it goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

C functions registered with a `lua_State` should return the number of return values they are pushing to the stack. Your function is not returning anything (to the Lua stack), but is telling Lua that it pushed a single value. As a result Lua will pop a value after your function finished and pass it to the caller. Probably the value that is popped is what you intended to call, but instead ended up calling the next thing on the stack - a number.

Try replacing the appropriate `return 1` statements with `return 0` and think carefully about the stack contents before each `return` to make sure you don't pop something.